# EFCore Include without navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

How can I do an Include without navigation property?
I can use the navigation property to get the subcategories, but after that I need to get all the ingredients for those subcategories (and I don't have the nav. property  for the ingredients because of the Aggregate root boundaries). And I don't know how I can get them.

[image: Database]
Code

```
var cat = _context.Categories.Include(s => s.SubCategories).ToList();
```

Comment: `Include` *is* for navigation properties. Your question doesn't make sense. Also, screenshots of code are not accepted in Stack Overflow

Comment: Please rephrase your question so that we can have the opportunity to understand your problem and try to help you.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't, not with Include.  For that, you'd need to use a separate request/query using the linked key as a clause.

But if you need to reference it in this way, why not make it a navigation property?  That's exactly what they're for.

So, if you have a category ID, then this is how you'd loop through the ingredients.   You should be able to work from this to get where you need to go:

```
var catId = 999;
foreach(var subCat in _context.SubCategories.Where(u => u.CategoryId == catId))
{
    foreach(var ingredient in _context.Ingredients.Where(u => u.SubCategoryId == subCat.Id))
    {
        // do work on 'ingredient'
    }
}
```

Comment: " For that, you'd need to use a separate request/query using the linked key as a clause" why a separate query when you can use a `join`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto that's an even better option.

Comment: I dont have the navigation property because of the DDD pattern. And how could I use a link query to get it?

Comment: DDD?  I'm not familiar with that pattern...  You'd do something like _context.SubCategories.Where(u => u.CategoryId == cat.Id).ToList()

Comment: Same way. Basically, for each SubCategory, _context.Ingredients.Where(u => u.SubCategoryId == subCat.Id).ToList()

There are definitely more efficient ways to do so though.

Comment: Can you share some example of that?

Comment: Yes but can you show an example of a more efficient way to do that.

Comment: Sure, but I would use Navigation Properties to do it, because that's exactly what they're there for.

Comment: @AdrianoSilva DDD "pattern" does not apply to EF entity (a.k.a. storage, persistence) model. EF model **requires** navigation properties in order to efficiently navigate/load/join relationships. Don't mix EF model with domain model. If you want to strictly follow DDD, create separate models and map between the two where needed.

Comment: @IvanStoev ok thank you for your response. I will take it in mind.

Comment: @IvanStoev, recent EF core versions are not that bad at mapping of aggregates directly to db tables. You can even configure it to always `Include`, or better use owned types for defining aggregate. And since EFCore6 it's possible to have mapping of entities which do not participate in migrations, so it's much easier to define read and write model in same context, if needed.